# Checkout, commit, push (using GIT integrated through publishing tool)

Tags: commit, vcs-checkout, madcap

We use MadCap (a publishing tool), which has direct integration with GIT. MadCap always, and only, pulls from the remote repository. I cannot tell MadCap to "read" my local repository.

So, I need to "recover" the repository from a certain point in time as a result of an audit request (i.e., We need ALL documentation from  5/1/2017). Now, like I said, we use integration to deal with GIT, but the integration does not provide the level of control needed to fulfill this request. And I need to provide the state of ALL our documentation from that given time. (I am new to working directly in GIT as well)

My question is this - will the following workflow/commands work to fulfill this request:
*git checkout sh1 (dated the last merge prior to 5/1). 
*commit
*push  (everyone is aware to refrain from pushing / pulling during this time)
*Access Madcap and Pull from remote, do what I need to do with documentation
*back to Git > git checkout master
*commit
*push
*Back to MadCap > Pull from remote

Comment: Can you point MadCap to different remotes or branches? You didn't specify which remote but if it's not your personal remote I would avoid force pushing over it, people tend to get mad about that sorta thing...

Comment: Yes, I can point MadCap to a different branch I believe. So, I gather,  checkout and create a branch at that checkout and commit?   I won't need to modify anything in this new branch.

Comment: Yeah, if you checkout the exact tag or hash which you're interested in, then checkout -b insertNameHere and push it you should be golden.